# How to efficiently extract Key Value and load to C# dictionary/HashMap from large files [File Size grows]?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please review the code and suggest better algorithm to efficiently extract key/value from files using multithread.

**Input** : FormNGFAddTab:First add Tab control inside Tabs control.परीक्षण

**Output** :

**Key** : FormNGFAddTab

**Value** : First add Tab control inside Tabs control.परीक्षण

**Separator** : ':'

**DataHolder/DataStructure** : Any[Dictionary/Hash Table/Array/Linked List]

**Solution 1:**

```
       public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> LoadActivityLookupParallelOptimized(string filePath)
            {
                Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                var lineCollection = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
                var newLookup = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
                int ParallelThreads = 100;
                Parallel.ForEach(lineCollection, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = ParallelThreads }, currentLine =>
                    {
                                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentLine))
                                {
                                    return;
                                }
                                if (currentLine.Substring(0, 2) == "//")
                                {
                                    return;
                                }
                                int iPos = currentLine.IndexOf(":", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                                int iiPos = currentLine.IndexOf("::", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                                string currentKey, currentValue;
                                if (iPos>0)
                                {
                                    if (iiPos>0)
                                    {
                                        currentKey = currentLine.Substring(0, iiPos);
                                        if ((iPos = currentLine.IndexOf(":", iiPos + 2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) > 0)
                                        {
                                            if ((iPos + 1) <= currentLine.Length)
                                            {
                                                currentValue = currentLine.Substring(iPos + 1);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                currentValue = string.Empty;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            return;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        currentKey = currentLine.Substring(0, iPos);
                                        if ((iPos + 1) <= currentLine.Length)
                                        {
                                            currentValue = currentLine.Substring(iPos + 1);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            currentValue = string.Empty;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    newLookup.TryAdd(currentKey.Trim(), currentValue.TrimEnd());
                                }
                    });
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Time taken: {0}ms", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
                return newLookup;
            }
```

I am using Parallel.Foreach to process all lines.

**Solution 2:**

```
     private static Dictionary<string, string> ProcessLine(string SourceFile)
            {
                Stopwatch sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                Dictionary<string, string> keyValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(SourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
                    {
                        string sLine = string.Empty;
                        string sKey = string.Empty, sValue = string.Empty;
                        try
                        {
                            while ((sLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                int iPos, iiPos;
                                sLine = sLine.Trim();
                                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sLine))
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }

                                ////Ignore comments
                                if (sLine.Substring(0, 2) == "//")
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }

                                ////Ignore if line does not contain :
                                if ((iPos = sLine.IndexOf(":", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) > 0)
                                {
                                    if ((iiPos = sLine.IndexOf("::", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) > 0)
                                    {
                                        sKey = sLine.Substring(0, iiPos);

                                        if ((iPos = sLine.IndexOf(":", iiPos + 2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) > 0)
                                        {
                                            if ((iPos + 1) <= sLine.Length)
                                            {
                                                sValue = sLine.Substring(iPos + 1);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                sValue = string.Empty;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sKey = sLine.Substring(0, iPos);
                                        if ((iPos + 1) <= sLine.Length)
                                        {
                                            sValue = sLine.Substring(iPos + 1);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            sValue = string.Empty;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    keyValue.Add(sKey.Trim(), sValue.TrimEnd());
                                }
                            }
                            sw2.Stop();
                            Console.WriteLine("Time taken: {0}ms", sw2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //Workflow.NET.Log logger = new Log();
                            //logger.LogError(ex, "Could not add key (" + sKey + ") from folder (" + SourceFile + "), Error:" + ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return keyValue;
            }

    Main()

     var filePath = @"M:\Dev3.0\Locales\hi-IN\NGF\NGFStandardMessages.txt";
                var result = LoadActivityLookupParallelOptimized(filePath);
                var result2 = ProcessLine(filePath);
                Console.ReadLine();

Results:

Algo 1: 3.1717 ms
Algo 2: 0.6234
LinesCount : 196 lines to process
```

Please share your thoughts on writing better algorithms for File Processing.

My Thoughts:

--> Using `IndexOf` is costly but it is the most efficient.

**Sample Key/Value in a line**:

**Line1** : FormNGFAddTab:First add Tab control inside Tabs control.परीक्षण

**Key** : FormNGFAddTab

**Value** : First add Tab control inside Tabs control.परीक्षण

**Common string in key** : FormNGF

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use multithreading for reading if you are after performance, so solution which uses `Parallel.ForEach()` is definetely better.
2. For really big files, you should not read all the text into memory. Instead you should create multiple file streams, split your file into reading sections and read those asynchroniously. For smaller files (200 lines is really small) your approach is fine.
3. Your algorithm can be simplified if you'd use `Split` method. For example:

   ```
   //remove comments
   var lineWithoutComments = line.Split(new []{"//"}, StringSplitOptions.None).FirstOrDefault();
   if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(lineWithoutComments)) continue;
   //split key and value
   var split = lineWithoutComments.Split(new []{":"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
   if (split.Length < 2) continue;
   var key = split[0].Trim();
   var value = split[1].Trim();
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I am concerned about performance as file size is close to 10MB i.e generating close to 1,00,000 keys. I tried the string.split operation but it costly when it comes to performance. I am trying to avoid IndexOf method which is costly. Searching for better algo to extract Key/Value pair.

Comment: Is it possible to write the algo in C++ and call it in c# to get best performance.